# How do I figure out which i2c device is which programmatically?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, i2c

I have 11 i2c device nodes on my system.

```
localhost user # ls /dev/i2c*
/dev/i2c-0  /dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-10  /dev/i2c-2  /dev/i2c-3  /dev/i2c-4  /dev/i2c-5  /dev/i2c-6  /dev/i2c-7  /dev/i2c-8  /dev/i2c-9
```

I can figure out which one is which by poking around in the /sys filesystem:

```
localhost devices # pwd                                                                                                              
/sys/bus/i2c/devices
localhost devices # ls -al                                                                                                           
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/i2c-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/i2c-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-10 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.2/i2c_designware.5/i2c-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-10508825:00 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.2/i2c_designware.5/i2c-10/i2c-10508825:00
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/i2c-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/i2c-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/i2c-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-5 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/i2c-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-7 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-8 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-9 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.3/i2c_designware.3/i2c-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-INT343B:00 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.2/i2c_designware.5/i2c-10/i2c-INT343B:00
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-INT343B:01 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.2/i2c_designware.5/i2c-10/i2c-INT343B:01
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-PRP0001:00 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-8/i2c-PRP0001:00
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-PRP0001:01 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.3/i2c_designware.3/i2c-9/i2c-PRP0001:01
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-SYNA7817:00 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-6/i2c-SYNA7817:00
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 10 15:45 i2c-SYNA7817:01 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-SYNA7817:01
```

The ones that I want are i2c-PRP0001-*, which I can see are currently symlinked to i2c-8 and i2c-9.

i2c offers no guarantee that these node numbers are stable (even across reboots). I would like to give my program the ability to look at an i2c device and determine if it's one I care about or not.

I could hack up a shell script to do basically what I just did on the command line, but is there a programmatic (C) way to find the device information (i.e. where does the kernel get the information that it writes to the sys filesystem)?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir + https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink + `strstr`

Comment: Basically it's a wrong approach to use raw interface for serial devices like I2C or SPI. The best way is to do driver in the kernel regarding corresponding framework.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I wasn't clear, sorry. I wasn't looking for the POSIX C API, I was looking for a way to query the device directly.

Comment: @0andriy the kernel driver for this device is still under development. I'm trying to mess with it in userspace to figure out what capabilities I'll have to play with once the kernel driver us usable.

Comment: @Nathan, yes, for development it's okay to use raw interface, though as developer you don't need to have fixed name, right? By the way, you may use `udev` to make symlinks based on ACPI IDs.